# Add element styling when JavaScript is disabled

Tags: javascript, html, css, noscript

I'm trying to avoid adding online styling when JS is being disabled.
For example, I'd like to hide an element in the body when JS is disabled, but i'd like to do it from external CSS only.

I'd like to avoid adding style like below

```
<noscript>
    <style>
    ...some style
    </style>

    <p class="no-js">You need Javascript enabled to view all of the content on this page.</p>
</noscript>

<body>
    <div>element to hide when js disabled</div>
</body>
```

Is there an alternative to this?
Thanks!

Comment: CSS has no ability to detect if, or when, JavaScript is disabled; instead use JavaScript to show the element when enabled, which implies that it will be hidden when JavaScript is disabled.

Comment: If it isn't broken, don't fix it ;-)

Answer (score 1):

> " *I'd like to hide an element in the body when JS is disabled* "

You can create a class with `display:none`, assign it to all elements you want to hide if javascript is disabled, and through javascript remove this class from these elements, if javascript is *disabled*, then this class will always apply and all elements with this class are not displayed

[**JS Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/hbL6xbaw/)

```js
var secrets = document.querySelectorAll('.secret');
for (var i in secrets) {
  secrets[i].classList.remove('secret');
}
```

```css
.secret {
  display: none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use `<noscript>` tag, for hide an element, in `<style>` tag make it `display:none`. there is no way to this with standalone css! but you can do this with javascript or etc, look other answer.

```
<noscript>
    <style type="text/css">
        .divtohide {display:none;}
    </style>
    <div class="divtohide">
    Javascript is disabled!
    </div>
</noscript>
```

Comment: Did you look at the question? The OP is already doing exactly that.

Comment: Yes that's my solution. But I was wondering if I can avoid  using styles in the noscript tag. I wonder if there is a better alternative.

Comment: if it goes up to me, i prefer to use this method, but i think there is no better way to do this, as i said you can use `javascript` but this way is very simple than other.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```html
<noscript>
  <style>
     #foo {
        display:none;
     }
  </style>
</noscript>
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, just use Javascript to hide the div that tells users that they need js enabled (if Javascript is disabled, obviously it cannot hide the div, and it will be shown).

```
<script>

  document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() { 
    document.getElementById('nojs').style.display = "none";
  });

</script>
```